# Copy selected radio to another radio

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

How could I copy the selected radio (from a radio group) to another one?
Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fu3oyscq/1/

This is my jquery

```
$("#copy input[name='copyOne']:checked").val(  $("#original input[name='selectOne']:checked").val()  )
```

Comment: listen for the change event and then try to set the value based on another radio

Comment: Are you coping (cloning) the radio button to another group or are you checking/unchecking a corresponding radio button in another group?

Answer (score 1):

This will do that what you require:

```
$("#original input").change(function () {
    var index = $(this).index();
    $("#copy input[name='copyOne']")[index].checked = true;
});
```

It fires when one of the original radios is selected. It retrieves the index of the original element. Selects the matching copied index and checkes it via the attribute `checked`.

http://jsfiddle.net/fu3oyscq/5/

Comment: You can just set the "checked" to true

Comment: @User true, safes computing time :-). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$("#original input[name='selectOne']").on('change', function(){
    $('#copy input').eq($(this).index()).prop('checked', true);
});
```